# Ошибка в отправке сообщения pyrogram и aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pyrogram

в моем случае, к аккаунту телеграмм - привязан бот pyrogram, берет сообщения по необходимым критериям с определенного чата, пересылает их через бота на aiogram v2.
В случае с текстом - работало замечательно все, но необходимо было привязать учёт картинок в сообщении.
Для этого - использовал этот код:

```
if message.photo:
    photo = list(message.photo.file_unique_id)
    photo[1], photo[-1] = "Q", "t-"
    photo = ''.join(str(x) for x in photo)
    await bot1.send_photo(photo=photo, caption=text, reply_markup=keyboard,chat_id=o[0])
```

Получаю ошибку, в которой указывается это: Wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. wrong last symbol

Методом исследования понял, что уникальный файл ид изображения - AQAD2tAxGysReEt-, в то время как pyrogram выдаёт AgAD2tAxGysReEs, именно поэтому в строке номер 3 менял 1 и последний символ, но ошибка оставалась. Что делать со всем этим?
Pyrogram и aiogram несовместимы?
Дело в том, что уникальный id изображения разный?
Очень прошу помочь, за два дня уже сломал голову... Или, если можно - как реализовать нечто похожее на это?

Comment: По file_unique_id нельзя отправить файл. Нужно использовать file_id

Comment: При использовании file_id - выходит следующее:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified

Comment: А откуда этот file_id берется? file_id действителен только в пределах одного бота, у другого бота этот же file_id будет недоступен

Answer (score -1):

Можешь скачивать фото и отправлять их

```
        file_id = msg.photo[3].file_id
        resp = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getFile?file_id={file_id}")
        img_path = resp.json()["result"]["file_path"]
        img = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{TOKEN}/{img_path}")
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img.content))
        if not os.path.exists("static"):
            os.mkdir("static")
        img_name = secrets.token_hex(8)
        img.save(f"static/{img_name}.png", format="PNG")
```